# Var dump called from within a function gives nonsensical results

Tags: php

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$url = $_POST["url"];
$active = $_POST["active"];

if($action == "add")
{
    var_dump($name); // Returns: String(10) "..."
    var_dump($url); // Returns: String(27) "..."
    var_dump($active); // Returns: String(2) "..."

    addSponsor(); // Returns: NULL NULL NULL
}

function addSponsor()
{
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($url);
    var_dump($active);
}
```

I think the quanundrum is self-implied, but even so I'll formulate this problem to the best of my ability.

WTH?

Variables are initialized at the very start of the script, yet half of my var_dumps return NULL

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access variables out of scope.  $name, $url, and $active are declared outside of addSponsor function; thus, the function thinks you're creating new variables and initializes them to null.

Answer (score 2):

To access those variables from within the function (without passing them in as arguments) you will need to use the `global` keyword to tell PHP that they have been declared in the global scope:

```
function addSponsor()
{
    global $name, $url, $active;
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($url);
    var_dump($active);
}
```

I would suggest specifying formal parameters, and passing the variables in as arguments to the function:

```
function addSponsor($name, $url, $active)
{
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($url);
    var_dump($active);
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

If you must, you can do this:

```
function addSponsor() {
    global $name, $url, $active;

    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($url);
    var_dump($active);
}
```

But global variables are bad form.  I would rewrite your script like so:

```
$post_vars = array(
    'name'   => $_POST["name"],
    'url'    => $_POST["url"],
    'active' => $_POST["active"]
);

if ($action === "add") {
    foreach ($post_vars as $post_var) {
        var_dump($post_var);
    }
    addSponsor($post_vars);
}

function addSponsor($post_vars = array()) {
    foreach ($post_vars as $post_var) {
        var_dump($post_var);
    }
}
```

Comment: Myself, `$name`, `$url`, and `$active` would be parameters to the function.

Answer (score 1):

the `addSponsor()` function is calling `var_dump` on what it sees as `NULL` because the variables you are trying to access are in the global scope. [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) page explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use these vars in your function you have to declare them global:

```
function addSponsor()
{
    global $name, $url, $active;
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($url);
    var_dump($active);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To make things easier to read, I'd highly advise coding a utility function like:

```
function DumpVar($obj) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($obj);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Also, please note that using output buffering ([ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), etc) is nice, but can be messed up by var_dump; something to watch for if you're in a page within an ob structure. I ran into that because of trying to capture a var_dump string in an output buffer for the JSON data to be dislpayed in an alert(). You'll be able to resolve it, but keep it in mind. An example of a successful ob HTML approach is in the comment [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php#77234).

Comment: I'd love to hear why someone demoted this. I'd have to say that due to the dearth of in-line debugging abilities in PHP, my little Dump() function is my most-used utility call and first lie of defense when troubleshooting some new issue. Don't know what the XML is you got back from a SOAP call, or the json data you've created, or many other things? Dump() !  :)